# Specify different EntryPoint for protocol launch

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, appxmanifest

I've been toying with this for a bit but haven't been able to get a working solution. I'm trying to set up my appxmanifest so that it uses a different EntryPoint for a protocol launch than for standard launch. Here's an example of my appxmanifest:

```
  <Applications>
<Application Id="App"
  Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
  EntryPoint="AppTest.App">
  <uap:VisualElements
    DisplayName="AppTest"
    Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
    Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
    Description="AppTest"
    BackgroundColor="transparent">
    <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png"/>
    <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
  </uap:VisualElements>
    <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol" EntryPoint="AppTest.Leaderboards">
            <uap:Protocol Name="test-leaderboards">
                <uap:DisplayName>View Test Leaderboards</uap:DisplayName>
            </uap:Protocol>
        </uap:Extension>
    </Extensions>
</Application>
```

I hoped the 'test-leaderboards' protocol to launch to the entrypoint for *AppTest.Leaderboards* and normal launch to provide *AppTest.App*. However, it always launches to *App*.

The *Leaderboards* and *App* pages look nearly identical except for name differences. I tried setting *Leaderboards* to the ApplicationDefinition build action, but then build errors ensue. If anyone has resources or ideas to try, help would be greatly appreciated.

I know that another option would be to handle this in the AppTest.App and navigate to the appropriate place from there. But I'd like to work through this possibility first. Please humor me :)